# How would I write a shader that supports 2 different texture coordinates?

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

Hi I am not very good with writing shaders. How would I make a shader that simply supports 2 texture coordinates so I can load up 2 different textures to be used at the same time but on different parts of my world? Right now I have 1 texturecoord variable setup and I load a texture through it using GraphicsDevice->SetTexture(0, &Texture); and making sure my VertexDeclaration and FVF both support that, but how can I add a second texture to this? Would I make it so that I make separate coordinates and link the coordinates to a texture? How would I write that?

Comment: You want to use one texture to control the other two (splat mapping), you will have a hard time to create assets if you go with a too home made solution. just my 2 cents ;-) ps. you might want to check out this link http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19930/where-to-start-when-building-a-3d-terrain-editor/19933#19933

Answer (score 1):

render code:

```
GraphicsDevice->SetTexture(0, &Texture);
GraphicsDevice->SetTexture(1, &SecondTexture);
```

hlsl declaration:

```
sampler Texture0 : register(s0);
sampler Texture1 : register(s1);
```

Use the vertices's other coordinates to sample Texture1.

Comment: thank you for that but could you tell me how I would write to the pixel shader that? I currently have Out.Color = tex2D(Tex0, In.Texture); How would I make it do a second texture? Would I just add Out.Color = tex2D(Tex1, In.Texture2); ?

Comment: I tried just adding under my Out.Color = tex2D(Tex0, In.Texture) Out.Color = tex2D(Tex1, In.Texture2) and it only payed attention to the last one (for obvious reasons). So how would I get it to use both samplers to output as you explained?

Comment: Well, you would need to mix the two colors into a single output.  There are literally infinite ways to do that.  What are you trying to achieve with your two different textures?  Perhaps you should post a second question, now that you have your textures available in your shader.

Comment: It would be nice just to get my answer here now that I have found someone that knows what they are talking about so could you please tell me how I can get the outputs into 1 thing?

Comment: I am trying to get it so that 1 part of my world has 1 texture and the other part has a different texture. I already had it colored to do that but now I need it so that the shader will follow

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/s1SDI.png this is a picture of what I want it to look like and I have the code to make it look this way but now i need a shader that combines the outputs using the code you showed me.. the problem with asking someone else is that they will tell me to use different code from what you told me to use and then it just gets annoyin

Comment: I was trying to tell you that you haven't given enough information for me to answer your followup question.  What are you trying to accomplish with your two textures?  I think the best place for you to explain that would be another question post.